# Writing the buffer to a text file

Tags: c++, c, file-io, buffer

I have a device connected to one of my ports, where I get data. I wrote an interface for it using C++. I can read the data fine, and print it to my screen.
I use

```
ser.readLine();
```

to read data.

I would like to write all the data I get to a text file.

I know that to write, data into a text file, I need to use the following.

```
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("test.txt");
  myfile <<  "dasd";
  myfile.close();
```

So my question is how can I write the data I get into a text file. 
Thanks

Comment: @Raxvan it is a SerialFetcher

Comment: I think you are looking for [this][1] link. It will help you. [1]:http://libserial.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ser.readLine();` returns a string you can do

```
 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("test.txt");
 myfile << ser.readLine();
 myfile.close();
```

Comment: It returns the line. You might want to make that into a loop.